# Extracting data from python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'@Kor3aYn @YouTube yeet', u'is_quote_status': False, u'in_reply_to_status_id': 805863281042878464L, u'id': 805864211544965122L, u'favorite_count': 0, u'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'timestamp_ms': u'1480967974922', u'entities': {u'user_mentions': [{u'id': 4249141216L, u'indices': [0, 8], u'id_str': u'4249141216', u'screen_name': u'Kor3aYn', u'name': u'YOUTUBE: Kor3aYn\U0001f1f0\U0001f1f7'}, {u'id': 10228272, u'indices': [9, 17], u'id_str': u'10228272', u'screen_name': u'YouTube', u'name': u'YouTube'}]
```

I need to get 'id_str' (4249141216). Can anyone help me with this?

My attempt:

```
ids =['4858458939']
if str((decoded['entities']['user_mentions']['id_str'])) == str(ids):
    code
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

```
if str((decoded['entities']['user_mentions'][0]['id_str']))
```

This works, however, how would I be able to check all user_mentions and not just the 0th one?

Answer (score 2):

Put a `[0]` after `['user_mentions']`, since that is a list.

If you want to check every mention, you'll have to iterate over them, e.g in a for loop

```
for mention in decoded['entities']['user_mentions']:
    do_something_with(mention['id_str'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This works. However, how would I be able to check all user_mentions and no just the 0th index?